# How do I know what traffic light is being processed?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 traffic lights that work with their own phase.
You can visit my demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eko24ive/EEDKP/4/), or see source code:

```
$(function() {
    traffic_lights = [
        [{color:'green' ,time:5 },
        {color:'yellow' ,time:3 },
        {color:'red' ,time:5 },],

        [{color:'green' ,time:10 },
        {color:'yellow' ,time:6 },
        {color:'red' ,time:10 },],
    ]


    for (var a = 0, f; a < traffic_lights.length; a++) {
        var g = traffic_lights[a];
        f = $("#c" + a);
        (function (a, d) {
            var b = 0,
                time = 0;
            return function s() {
                time || (a.css({"background-color": d[b].color}), time = d[b].time, b = ++b % d.length);
                a.html(time);
                time--;
                window.setTimeout(s, 1e3);
            }
        })(f, g)();
    }

})
```

How do I know which traffic light (span id) is being processed and what its color is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get it right, the span is `f`, so its id attribute is `"c" + a`.  you can get its background color with `f.css('background-color').

edit: the question is really unclear, which scope and lifetime are you interested in?  you should probably use `a` instead of `f` inside `s`.  as you're already doing.  so i'm confused about what problem you think you have.